# How works returning an object by reference

Tags: c++, oop, reference, operator-overloading

As i understand it is my reference SomeClass &ref=b; After that b = ref; Then c = b; SomeClass &ref2=c; then c=ref2 . But am I calling the operator = witch i have reloaded  when b=ref or c = ref2 ? Something like that a.operator=(ref) ?

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass()
    {
        a = 5;
    }
    SomeClass(int l_a)
    {
        a = l_a;
    }

    SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass& l_copy)
    {
        this->a = l_copy.a;
        return *this;
    }

    int a;
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass a;
    SomeClass b(1);
    SomeClass с(6);
    с = b = a;

}
```

Comment: `c=b=a;` is the same as `c=(b=a);`, which is the same as `c.operator=(b.operator=(a));`. There is no `operator=` called for `a`. Note that assignment has _right-to-left associativity_. `b.operator=(a)` therefore returns a reference to `b`, which is used as an argument for `c.operator=` call.

Comment: I have asked how objects transmit by reference when b = ref (SomeClass &ref=b) Am i use my reloaded operator = ?

Comment: What is a "reloaded" operator?

Comment: Are you asking about `SomeClass& ref = b; b = ref;` case? If so, why your code does something completely different? There is no `ref` in it. Please, edit the code to match your question.

Comment: @DanielLangr doy you mean that c.operator= (ref) where  SomeClass &ref=b ?

Comment: @AndréCaceres  SomeClass& operator= ...

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean **overloading** the assignment operator.

Comment: @AndréCaceres yes

Comment: @DanielLangr return *this returns b .But as i set that my type will be SomeClass&  it returns a reference on my object b. Somebody told me that my reference on my object looks likeSomeClass& ref = b; (we do not see when it is created). Then my object b gets object b by reference (ref)

Comment: @ZELIBOBA You can rewrite `c=b=a;` as `b=a; SomeClass& ref=b; c=ref;` as well with the same effect. There is no difference between `c=b` and `c=ref` at the end. Still not clear what is your question, sorry.

Comment: @DanielLangr I'll try to explain how i understand that code.You`ll tell me if i am right and then i explain what i have tried to ask. 1) Let's start from b=a. 2) Object B calls the assignment operator where parameter is A. 3)My 'function' returns *this (As i know this - the address of b , *this - the object b) 4) I set that my type of returning value will be a reference on my object B , so my reference will looks something like that SomeClass& ref=b; 5)Now , when we created reference on object B , we can return it 6) I had b=a , but now it must be b=ref (i returned the object by ref) 7) c=b ..

Comment: @ZELIBOBA It's correct up 5). 6) does not make sense. The whole `b=a` returns a reference to `b` (`ref`). `ref` virtually substitutes `b=a`, not `a`.

Answer (score 1):

If you had:

```
void operator=(const SomeClass& l_copy)
    {
        this->a = l_copy.a;
    }
```

Then your assignments operations would be limited to:

```
b = a;
c = b;
```

By returning the reference you can chain assignments as in:

```
c = b = a;
// c.operator = (b.operator = (a));

//1: b.operator= ("ref a")
//2: c.operator= ("ref b")
```

Answer (score 1):

By overloading the operator = in `SomeClass`, you are doing copy-assignment `lhs = rhs` (Eg : `c = b`, c is `lhs` and b is `rhs`). Because it returns a reference matching `SomeClass& operator=` expected parameter type, you can chain multiple copy-assignments such as `c = b = a`.